# Android: how to check if two rotated views overlap

Tags: android

i have a button which rotates in the middle of the screen using an ObjectAnimator and another button (which will be a square or a circle) moving back and forth, which sometimes does overlap on the first.

I need to know when the first button is covered by the second one, however the first button does rotate, so i can't just compare the two rectangles.

Does anybody know a solution?

*edit*

I've been trying pturner's solution but there have been a few issues that i can't fix anyhow:

- The rotating button's rectangle's values seem to be generated from the origin of the axis, rather than the origin of the button, thus the moving button will believe he's intersecting the rotating button in the top-left side of the screen.
- When the rotating button rotates, the rectangles' values will eventually invert, becoming negative and thus flipping left/right and top/bottom. As a result at certain angles the moving button believes to always be overlapping, while at some other it believes to never overlap.

I really have no clue how to fix those issues, i'll just leave this question here hoping for someone to know a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to get the rects for both views, and then transform them with the matrix, something along the lines of:

```
Matrix matrix1 = button1.getMatrix();
Rect box1 = new Rect();
button1.getDrawingRect(box1); 
Rectf boxf1 = new RectF(box1);
matrix1.mapRect(boxf1); 

Matrix matrix2 = button2.getMatrix();
Rect box2 = new Rect();
button2.getDrawingRect(box2);
Rectf boxf2 = new RectF(box2); 
matrix2.mapRect(boxf2);

boolean intersect = boxf1.intersect(boxf2);
```

Comment: mapRect requires a RectF, not a Rect. While getDrawingRect requires a Rect and not a RectF. I can't cast a RectF to Rect and i can't do the opposite either. What now? D: *edit* i can instantiate a new rectF given a rect, i'll try and see if it works. :)

Comment: Ya just added the conversion to Rectf, a little messy but should work now

Comment: Neither this solution or the usual rectangles one seem work, they always return false, which is very weird as the two buttons overlap alot. [link](http://i.imgur.com/X3p8PwC.png) I've set the non-rotating button to change text when it overlaps, yet nothing happens. I've tried to make it set a different text when they do not overlap and that always triggers. I have no clue. :x

Comment: I've been toying with the values and i found that all the variables inside of both box1 and box2 have value 0 (toShortString displays [0,0][0,0]). Apparently getDrawingRect is not working. maybe it's due the animation?

Comment: Could it be that when you are pulling `getDrawingRect` it is before the view has been drawn?

Comment: I think it's unlickely: the buttons are created in the xml, the mainActivity istantiates a ButtonGest class that sets the animations, which then istantiates a thread that keeps checking if the buttons collide every 50 ms.I've tried to call the invalidate() method to force the redraw but it changes nothing, the same thing happens with the buttons that aren't animated. So, i have no clue. :/

Comment: Do you have the ability to add some of your code up? Tried a little test on two random views and am getting values filled in, might be something with your view references?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/FUKa3KuN, the issue is that for some weird reason the Thread runs only once, i've tried to put a counter and a random value, then setting it into the button, but only one value gets written, regardless of wether i set a sleep or not. I have no clue as to why this happens :O

Comment: There's a chance that this is due to the code not running on the main thread, see: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads

Try using https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable, long)

with a `Runnable` that then posts a delayed runnable again when it is complete (I recommend this for test code only, would be better for the delayed runnable to be managed by the activity)

Comment: I've c/p'd the same code in a new project because sometimes Android Studio divides by zero but this is not the case this time. I'm very uncomfortable with the idea of having a delayed view with a runnable that posts a delayed runnable...to be honest i have no clue about that. :s **cuts veins**

Comment: Here's a modified version using delayed runnabled. Equivalent to your thread sleeping and changing things, more android friendly hopefully. Might have some compile issues becuase I didn't actually run this. http://pastebin.com/1QWE5UcF

Comment: Issue: mHandler does not have postDelayed, which is weird since it is listed in the docs. Everything else seems to don't have any issue tho.

Comment: Imported the wrong Handler, happens all the time. Check your imports.

Comment: Oh, wopsie! Well, it does work much better now, however the results are kinda wrong: The rectangles' values never change and the second button is set as overlapping when it's in the left side of the screen(apparently it switches state right in the middle of the screen). The rectangles' values are [0,0][X,Y]. The first one is always 0,0, while the other are two fixed amounts.  I'm dazed. =.=

Comment: Did some extra tests to find the issue and it appears that while in the left side of the screen, both the RectF boxes update the new positions, even when one of the two is not moving at all, while on the second half of the screen the non-moving RectF is displayed as such. However, by flipping the rotating button, the other one will display to be overlapping at different times, which is good as it means it's working a little. However i have no idea regarding the fact that the detection itself is wrong. :x Should i upload the project?

Comment: This is the end of the road for what I can do to help, good luck figuring it out.

Comment: Well, one of the issues is that the rotating button's rectangle appears to be near the axis at 0,0, adding a value to the rectangle's left and right values will add different values than the one added (408 becomes 258,what). Then, when the button rotates the rect's values get inverted at some point, thus the left becomes the right, which is obvious... I'll just update the question (if stackoverflow allows me to) and i'll hope for some android enthusiast to know a fix. Meanwhile i'll scrap the project completely. Ty for your support tho, i really appreciated it.